# Photo and Text positioning CSS+HTML

Tags: html, css, web

How can I stylize a photo and a text to make the effect as seen below in my example photo. Any ideas?

[CLICK HERE FOR EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5ZT6.png)

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are 10's of ways you can go for it. I could have gone with `<figure>` in HTML5. So, here is the code for same.

```css
.card{
  width:200px;
}
.card-image{
  display:block;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
   border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
.bottom-caption{
  font-size:18px;
  line-height:24px;
  text-align:center;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  padding: 4px 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<figure class="card">
  <img src="https://cdn.tutsplus.com/webdesign/uploads/legacy/tuts/399_bootstrap_sass/preview.png" alt="sass" class="card-image">
  <figcaption class="bottom-caption"> 1 MEMBER </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you need?

https://jsfiddle.net/ev0op09q/2/

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700,400);
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.img-container {
  width:200px;
  border-radius:5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float:left;
}
.img-name{
  background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    margin: -4px 0 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:16px;
    font-weight:700;
}
.content {
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:30px;
}
a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/cats-q-c-200-200-3.jpg" alt="cat">
<p class="img-name">Cool cat</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>Cats love you</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
  <a href="#">Click me</a>
</div>
```